# let $f(x)$ is polynomial function , $f(x+2)-f(x) = 6x^2+12x$ , $f(1)-f(0)=?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

Let $f$ is polynomial function.

$$f(x+2)-f(x) = 6x^2 +12x$$

$$f(1)-f(0)=?$$

I found that $f(x)$ is 3rd order ,

and use some coefficient $a, b, c, d$, but that's too hard to solve.

I want to use difference equation /recurrence or any smart way.

Comment: Write it as $[f(x+2)-f(x+1)]+f(x+1)-f(x)$

Answer (score 7):

Evaluating the functional equation at $x=0$ and $x=-2$ gives that
$$f(2)-f(0)=0\\f(0)-f(-2)=0$$
Thus:
$$f(-2)=f(0)=f(2)=a$$
This gives us that $f(x)=g(x)*x(x-2)(x+2)+a$.

Substituting $f(x)$ back into the initial equation gives $g(x)=1$
and hence $f(1)-f(0)=-3$

Comment: (+1)a typo in the second equation: $f(0)-f(\color{red}{2})=0$. Should be $f(0)-f(\color{green}{-2})=0$

Comment: Thank you for your kindness